# require('name')() vs requires ('name');

Tags: node.js

Saw this style of import on Github and was wondering why it is used? What's the deal with the **()** in the end?

```
const logger = require('pino')()
```

vs

```
const logger = require('pino');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const logger = require('pino')();
```

is equivalent to

```
const loggerFn = require('pino');
const logger = loggerFn();
```

Does this help?

---

Let me give a more concrete example. Consider

**foo.js**

```js
module.exports = function() {
    return 1;
};
```

and now in some other module

```js
const fooFn = require('foo');
// fooFn is our defined function
const foo = fooFn();
// foo is 1
```

versus

```js
const foo = require('foo')();
// foo is 1
```

which is equivalent.

---

So basically with `pino` package when you `require('pino')` you get a function which you then have to call. That's how the package was designed.

Comment: So it is basically to initialize the variable?

Comment: @sander kind of, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you just need to understand what `require` does. When `require` is called, NodeJS returns the value of `module.exports` in the module you are requesting. In the case of [pino](https://github.com/pinojs/pino/blob/master/pino.js), `module.exports` is equal to a function, so when you add the parenthesis to the end of the `require` statement, you are simply calling the function returned by `require`.